# Split aggregate root to avoid concurrency conflicts

Tags: concurrency, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Readying more and more about *Aggregate Roots*, specially I-DDD from Vaughn Vernon, I came with a question about concurrency.

A system is accessed by a number of users concurrently. The (current) *Core Domain* is about "enrolments" to an educational center, so there is a `Student` entity representing the main customer of the business. `Student` is an *Aggregate Root* and has, of course, a lot of information.

Let's say a `Student` has a `PersonalAddress` and `AcademicInformation` (past schools, grades, ...) both modeled as *Value Objects* inside the *Aggregate*, and -for the sake of argument- there is no other *Entity* in the same *Aggregate*. The `Student` *Aggregate* uses optimistic concurrency with something like version property in the *Entity*, so any change to its data will increment that version.

The thing is if two different users try to modify the `PersonalAddress` and the `AcademicInformation` of the same `Student` at the same time, one of those attempts will fail, even though address and academic information are totally unrelated; while both are *VO*, they belong to the same *Aggregate*.

I thought I could split the *Aggregate* to avoid concurrency conflicts since there is no truly invariants related to `PersonalAddress` and `AcademicInformation` besides both "belongs" to the same `Student`. But those are *VO* without identity for themselves. I would have to create another *Entity* and put both in different *Aggregate Roots*, both containing pieces of information related to the same student, so those can be modified concurrently.

So the questions are:

1. How could avoid the concurrency conflict of modifying unrelated information of the same *Entity* (`Student`) that is modeled as *Value Objects* (`PersonalAddress`, `AcademicInformation`)?
2. Is a "good approach"™ to split the `Student` *Aggregate* in two or more different *Aggregate Roots*, as I explained before?
3. Even if this particular situation could be solved by other means (I would be grateful if share that), how is that problem addressed in a more general perspective?

I think all depends in how frequently users try to modify the information concurrently and, based on that, decide if split the aggregate is worthwhile... but I don't know.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can use optimistic concurrency in other way: based on old values, not on version number. E.g. command to change Student should looks like new ChaneStudentCmd { StudentId = ...; OldAddressStreet = "xxx"; NewAddressStreet = "yyy" }, implementation should ensure that current strret is "xxx" before changing it. If it is not "xxx" concurrency exception should be thrown.

2) I think there are no reasons to split the aggregate.

3) The general approach can be using more specific update commands, not simple "update all student properties". Business layer should have information about that exacly user wants to update. With this information it will be able to process update gracefully, in consideration of concurrency and other demands.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion you can keep it as it is, which is the simplest approach. However, keeping unrelated properties or methods in the one Aggregate/Entity/Class breaks "high cohesion" rule.
So I wonder if situation you have is a "smell" of undiscovered Bounded Contexts. Do `PersonalAddress` and `AcademicInformation` belong to the same Bounded Context? I don't know your domain and use cases, but you should consider this.

Answering your questions:

Ad 1. Avoid conflicts by separating unrelated informations into different Bounded Contexts or Aggregates. There still can be concurrent conflicts on related informations, though.

Ad 2. It is a "good approach" to model Bounded Contexts and Aggregates properly (although it is not easy ;) ). So concurrent conflicts and unrelated informations are "smells" which let you know that you missed something in your model.

Ad 3. Again, proper Bounded Contexts and Aggregates modelling.

I don't claim that in every situation there is a way to avoid what you encountered by separating BCs and Aggregates, but I do feel that it is possible. I don't claim, that it is always true not to have unrelated properties and methods in one Aggregate, but it is where "high cohesion" rule leads me to.